# Error on user authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner of laravel framework. I am now having problem in authentication in laravel 5.2. I tried but I can't find error.

Email and password is correct but it is redirecting to login page.

Here is my DB

```
+----+-------+-----------------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name  | email           | password | phone | remember_token | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Admin | admin@gmail.com | 111111   |       | NULL           | 2017-01-03 05:40:06 | 2017-01-03 05:40:06 |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------+-------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\User;

use DB;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        if( !Auth::check() ) {
            return view('user/index');
        } else {
            return view('user/profile');
        }
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if( Auth::attempt( array( 

            "email" => "admin@gmail.com",
            "password" => "111111",

        ) ) ) {
            return redirect('user/profile');
        } else {
            return redirect('user/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why password is stored without Hash  ? ? store `$2y$10$POrpktOrPPwuj4u3P1vQeekle6xPnJTDmNYHqIGHDqTeymnZA4BFC` instead of 111111 in the database .and then try,  the string i gave you is the Hash of '111111'.

Comment: Which part of the if statement is it reaching? Also check that your server has sessions enabled and that you have configured your .env file correctly

Comment: Laravel expects your password in database to be hashed. :/

Comment: Have you checked with hash

Comment: I stored password without Hash. I will try with hash. Thanks to all. :-)

Comment: You can simply go into 'php artisan tinker' and get the user and change the password to the hashed one. $u = App\User::first(); $u->password = bcrypt('11111'); $u->save();

Answer (score 3):

In Database you need to store password in encrypted format.Auth::attempt() will convert the password into encrypted form and compare with the password in database.

During data insertion into the database you need to use

> bcrypt($password);